# Upgraded HVM AMI won't launch on m4 instance types

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, bitnami, hvm

I am using the Bitnami Tomcat on Ubuntu AWS AMI for my application servers. I want to upgrade my old PV image to be hardware virtualized (HVM) so I can take advantage of the m4 instance types on AWS.

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330721/amazon-ec2-how-to-convert-an-existing-pv-ami-to-hvm/26276763#26276763) for upgrading an existing Ubuntu PV image to an HVM image, and everything works fine up until I try to launch a new instance based on the image created from that process.

I can launch new instances if I use the older m3 instance types, but if I try to launch an m4.large I get this error from the AWS Management Console:

> Launch Failed The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace
>   product is not supported. Please see the AWS Marketplace site for more
>   information about supported instance types, regions, and operating
>   systems.

Is there something left in the original boot volume that won't allow this image to run on an hvm type? I'm two days into this process and I can see the finish line, but I can't quite get there!

Comment: Yes, there's something "left on" the volume, but not in the sense that you may be thinking... it's out-of-band licensing metadata, accessible only to the EC2 infrastructure, associating the volume with the Marketplace product.  I think @MattHouser has the right idea, the Marketplace configuration doesn't support the instance class/type change. (Some marketplace license fees vary by instance type).

Comment: Does this help? https://community.bitnami.com/t/ami-launch-instance-fails/51161/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your EC2 instance was launched from an application in the AWS Marketplace.

Many AWS Marketplace apps only support using certain EC2 instance types. It's quite possible that your EC2 instance, at the time that it was launched, supported M3 instance types and not M4 instance types (especially if M4 did not exist at that time).

Based on the error message you are reporting, it's highly likely that your EC2 instance is falling into this situation. There may be no solution aside from launching a fresh EC2 instance from the Marketplace as M4.